# Spring-batch -- compare data from csv and update records in Salesforce accordingly

Tags: csv, spring-boot, salesforce, spring-batch

I have data in csv format which I want to search in salesforce object and remove certain records from salesforce based on certain criteria. I HAVE to use spring batch. What should be the best approach to execute this project?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to help you, we need to see what you've tried.  Please post whatever code you have attempted in your solution so we can better help.

Comment: I have not started to code yet. I am confused about structure to use for this. If I use Task with reader, processor and writer, what i want to know how to use that structure or I should do it in 2 steps?

Answer (score 0):

based on certain criteria...

I would create an run a query in the workbench.
Extract the Id's of the records and put those Id's in a csv per object.
Then use data loader to delete records (with the Id's in the csv)